# How to adjust the rows and columns?

Tags: c, function

I wrote this code and I want it to be 1 row and 2 columns like. I used 2d array but when I run the code it does not allow to enter the name and date of birth. Then how will it appear in text file if it is not accepting input?

**Expected output**

```
Name     Date of Birth
John     02\02\1999
```

**This is the code**

```
int main(char *name, size_t namesize, char *dob, size_t dobsize){
    char listing[1][2] = {"Name ","Date of birth "};
    char *another_list[1][2];
    int i, j;
    FILE * fp;
    fp = fopen("/home/bilal/Documents/file.txt","w+"); 


    for (i=0; i<1; i++){
        for(j=0; j<2; j++){
          printf("Enter your %s: ",listing[i][j]);
          fgets(another_list[i][j], sizeof(another_list[i][j]), stdin);

          for (i=0; i<1; i++){
            for (j=0; j<2; j++){
                fputs(listing[i][j], fp);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char listing[1][2] = {"Name ","Date of birth "};` should be `char listing[2][15] = {"Name ","Date of birth "};` or better yet ``char listing[][15] = {"Name ","Date of birth "};``. Also, `fgets` wants a string as destination but you are using a `char`

Comment: No. It didn't solve.

Comment: Of course it didn't solve, there are more errors

Comment: Don't change the signature of main.  It will screw you up. Compile your code with -Wall and start fixing all the warnings it gives.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/5fJ46X - in case you need help with getting the warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int main(char *name, size_t namesize, char *dob, size_t dobsize)
```

Valid signatures for `main` are:

```
int main(void)
```

or

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

The dimensions are wrong:

```
char listing[1][2] = {"Name ","Date of birth "};
```

let the compiler count for you, the first dimension is not required:

```
char listing[][15] = {"Name ","Date of birth "};
```

and since those are not modifiable titles:

```
const char *listing[] = {"Name ","Date of birth "};
```

All those loops are a mess, two loops are enough.

Your code working:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char *listing[] = {"Name", "Date of birth"};
    char data[2][51];
    int done = 0;
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("/home/bilal/Documents/file.txt", "w+");
    puts("Press CTRL+D to exit");
    while (!done)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            printf("Enter your %s: ", listing[i]);
            // Scan until \n with buffer protection
            if (scanf(" %50[^\n]", data[i]) != 1)
            {
                done = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!done)
        {
            fprintf(fp, "%s %s\n", data[0], data[1]);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Didn't think you would do the homework for them.  I considered, but got busy... :)

Comment: Yeah :) I don't like to spoonfeed but with as many errors it was very difficult to enumerate them one by one